# attr_accessor and password validation on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, attr-accessor

I have this code in my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password

  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false },
                    :format => { :with => /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/ },
                    :length => 7..128
  validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :confirmation => true,
                       :length => 6..128

  private
    def encrypt_password
      return unless password
      self.encrypted_password = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
    end
end
```

Now in my controller when I'm updating some user fields with

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

the password field is always validated, even when it is not set in the params hash. I figured that this is happening because of the attr_accesor :password which always sets password = "" on update_attributes.

Now I could simply skip the validation of password if it is an empty string:

```
validates :password, :presence => true,
                     :confirmation => true,
                     :length => 6..128,
                     :if => "password.present?"
```

But this doesn't work because it allows a user to set an empty password.

Using update_attribute on the field I'd like to change is not a solution because i need validation on that attribute.
If I pass in the exact parameter with

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user][:fieldname])
```

it doesn't solve the problem because it also triggers password validation.

Isn't there a way to prevent attr_accesor :password from always setting password = "" on update?

Comment: I'm not sure you want the `:attr_accessor` for `:password`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**New answer**

This works for me:

```
validates :password, :presence     => true,
                     :confirmation => true,
                     :length       => { :minimum => 6 },
                     :if           => :password # only validate if password changed!
```

If I remember correctly it also took me some time to get this right (a lot of trial and error). I never had the time to find out exactly why this works (in contrast to `:if => "password.present?"`).

**Old answer - not really useful for your purpose (see comments)**
I get around this problem by using a completely different action for password update (user#update_password). Now it is sufficient to only validate the password field

```
:on => [:create, :update_password]
```

(and also only make it accessible to those actions).

Here some more details:

in your routes:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    GET :edit_password # for the user#edit_password action
    PUT :update_password # for the user#update_passwor action
  end
end
```

in your UsersController:

```
def edit_password
  # could be same content as #edit action, e.g.
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
def update_password
  # code to update password (and only password) here
end
```

In your edit_password view, you now have a form for only updating the password, very similar to your form in the edit view, but with :method => :put and :url => edit_password_user_path(@user)

Comment: is there anywhere I can read more about the `update_[something]` method you're using there? It's some kind of on-the-fly meta method, I guess but I can't actually find any info and have searched the docs for like 4 minutes. It seems really useful especially if you don't have dirty methods on the password field (such as when it's not a field in the db, which should be always).

Comment: thanks, I see what you're doing now, you have different views for the password update action

Comment: Oh, just noticed you weren't the one who asked the question - that puts your comment in a slightly different context for me :) To answer your question (since you probably know how to do it): it's all custom methods

Comment: Hmmm maybe I'm doing it wrong but I can't get the validation to accept two actions like you did with `:on => [:create, :update_password]`

Comment: Sorry - I had to recall the solution from memory. Now I came back home an checked my coding -> validations only support :update or :create for :on. I think I stumbled upon this as well ... The solution that is working for me is even more simple. I'll update it above.

Comment: Thanks, that finally worked. :) But can't say why, seems a bit odd what's happening there. In the meantime I figured out another way to do it, but your solution looks a bit simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I have started using to get round this problem is this:

Start using ActiveModel's built in `has_secure_password` method.

At console

```
rails g migration add_password_digest_to_users password_digest:string
rake db:migrate
```

In your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  attr_accessible :login_name, :password, :password_confirmation

  # secure_password.rb already checks for presence of :password_digest
  # so we can assume that a password is present if that validation passes
  # and thus, we don't need to explicitly check for presence of password
  validates :password, 
    :length => { :minimum => 6 }, :if => :password_digest_changed?

  # secure_password.rb also checks for confirmation of :password 
  # but we also have to check for presence of :password_confirmation
  validates :password_confirmation, 
    :presence=>true, :if => :password_digest_changed?
end
```

And finally,

```
# In `config/locales/en.yml` make sure that errors on
# the password_digest field refer to "Password" as it's more human friendly 

en:
  hello: "Hello world"

  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        password_digest: "Password"
```

Oh, one more thing: watch the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1)

Comment: This doesn't work correctly because `user.update_attributes(password: "", password_confirmation: "")`returns true (but isn't passed through to the database). It actually does not change it to an empty password, but error handling in the controller will break.

Comment: Why will error handling break? Do you actually want an error message when the user submits a blank password?

Comment: I don't want to display a success message if there wasn't actually any success ... it would confuse the user. But I could implement another if statement in the controller that explicitly checks for an empty password. It just doesn't seem right that update_attributes returns true if it actually didn't update anything.